# Update year for date on all dates > Dec 26, 2015

Tags: mysql

How can I update the year on all dates over 2016 in my DB? My application has by mistake saved dates after Dec 27, 2015 as Dec 27, 2016 for some reason (have already found the error, fixing it) and now I need to change the YEAR for those dates to 2015 again. I'm using MySql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2013-%m-%d %T');
```

OR

```
UPDATE table
    SET date_col=DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'2013-%m-%d %T') WHERE YEAR(date_col)>2015;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you expand on this to keep the hours, minutes and seconds intact too? My format is HHHH-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
update tab set date_column = DATE_SUB(date_column,INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
where date_column >= '2016-12-27'
```

Comment: This looks like what I want, but dont I have to work the table in somwehere?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
update table 
SET table.field = REPLACE(table.field, YEAR(table.field), '2015') 
WHERE YEAR(table.field) < '2016';
```

Comment: Um, shurely shome mishtake